# Sublime text - remove space between the tabs and the top edge of the screen

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, user-experience

Is there any way to remove the space between the UI tabs and the top edge of the screen in Sublime Text?

It is very nice being able to select tabs with a mouse, without having to aim. When the top of the tabs is right next to the top of the screen - I don't have to be precise to click on the tab - I can just move the mouse up vertically as far as I want - the cursor won't go any further cause its already on the edge of the screen.

[image]
[image]

Surprisingly so many software suites these days entirely miss on this great usability feature, putting useless pixels between the tabs and the edge of the screen.

I really hope someone could point out a way to remove that space in Sublime Text.

Comment: You can probably fix this by finding the correct option in your .sublime-theme file, though I'm not sure which one it is. An alternative option would be to use a theme that has rectangular tabs that take up the entire height. Something like this: http://i.imgur.com/5trC1Dm.png

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can't imagine why I didn't think of this myself.
PS maybe you should post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably fix this by finding the correct option in your .sublime-theme file, though I'm not sure which one it is. An alternative option would be to use a theme that has rectangular tabs that take up the entire height. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxl37.png

The one I displayed in that screenshot was [Spaceblack](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Spaceblack) which you can install through Package Control.